# Consultar un DNI en diferentes tablas PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Buen día, estoy haciendo un login con CodeIgniter, el usuario ingresa un dato que está registrado en una de las dos tablas, como puedo hacer para que encuentre y valide ese dato en una de las tablas, estaba intentando hacer esto pero no me valida.

```
public function getUser($dni)
{
    if ($dni==$dni) {
        $result = $this->db->query("select * from empleados where dni ='$dni'");
    }else{
        $result = $this->db->query("select * from encargados where dni ='$dni'");
    }
    if($result->num_rows() > 0){
        return $result->row();
    }else{
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Que intentas lograr con esto `($dni==$dni)`?

Comment: Generalmente, se usa una sola tabla de usuarios, empleados en tu caso, y los identificas mediante un campo específico, ya sea departamento, rol, tipo, etc.; de lo contrario, tienes que hacer consulta en cada tabla para ver si devuelve resultados.

Comment: Veo un modelo problemático. **Todos los encargados son empleados**, y eso podría llevar a **redundancia de datos** y a código spaghetti y pesado para obtener algo sencillo (aquí mismo tenemos un ejemplo, leer dos tablas para buscar un dato). ¿Por qué no manejas una tabla `persona` y manejas los cargos en una tabla adicional. Así, para todo aquello genérico (como el DNI) consultarías solo a la tabla `persona`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Por lo que logro entender buscas hacer algo así:
Es decir primero intenta encontrar si existe un empleado y si no intenta encontrar si existe un encargado y si ninguno existe regresa null

```
public function getUser($dni)
{
    $result = $this->db->query("select * from empleados where dni ='$dni'");
    if($result->num_rows() > 0){
        return $result->row();     
    }else{
        $result = $this->db->query("select * from encargados where dni ='$dni'");
    }
    if($result->num_rows() > 0){
        return $result->row();
    }else{
        return null;
    }

}
```